# Flot javascript graphing: setData for multiple series

Tags: javascript, flot

I am trying to plot 6 time series at once, and update their values every few ms.

Here is how I initially plot the data which works fine:

```
var d1 = [];
var d2 = [];
var d3 = [];
var d4 = [];
var d5 = [];
var d6 = [];

d1 = getRandomData(d1, totalPoints);
d2 = getRandomData(d2, totalPoints);
d3 = getRandomData(d3, totalPoints);
d4 = getRandomData(d4, totalPoints);
d5 = getRandomData(d5, totalPoints);
d6 = getRandomData(d6, totalPoints);

var plot = $.plot("#placeholder", [{
data: d1,
lines: { show: true, fill: false }
}, {
data: d2,
lines: { show: true, fill: false }
}, {
data: d3,
lines: { show: true, fill: false }
}, {
data: d4,
lines: { show: true, fill: false }
}, {
data: d5,
lines: { show: true, fill: false }
}, {
data: d6,
lines: { show: true, fill: false }
}]);
```

But my update function doesn't work:

```
function update() {

d1 = getRandomData(d1, totalPoints);
d2 = getRandomData(d2, totalPoints);
d3 = getRandomData(d3, totalPoints);
d4 = getRandomData(d4, totalPoints);
d5 = getRandomData(d5, totalPoints);
d6 = getRandomData(d6, totalPoints);

plot.setData([d1, d2, d3, d4, d5, d6]);

// Since the axes don't change, we don't need to call plot.setupGrid()
plot.draw();
setTimeout(update, updateInterval);

}
//update();
```

When I uncomment and call `update()`, the graph goes blank. But I know data is being loaded fine initially without calling it.

How can I update my d arrays and redraw the graph properly?

Comment: `d1 = getRandomData(d1, totalPoints);` -- why is d1 both assigned from and passed into this function?

Answer (score 6):

`setData` and the data argument to `plot` both take data [formatted the same way](https://github.com/flot/flot/blob/master/API.md#data-format).

So, create a reusable function:

```
 getSeriesObj = function() {
   return [
    {
      data: getRandomData(d1, totalPoints),
      lines: { show: true, fill: false }
    }, {
      data: getRandomData(d2, totalPoints),
      lines: { show: true, fill: false }
    }, {
      data: getRandomData(d3, totalPoints),
      lines: { show: true, fill: false }
    }, {
      data: getRandomData(d4, totalPoints),
      lines: { show: true, fill: false }
    }, {
      data: getRandomData(d5, totalPoints),
      lines: { show: true, fill: false }
    }, {
      data: getRandomData(d6, totalPoints),
      lines: { show: true, fill: false }
    }
  ];
}
```

For the intial plot:

```
var plot = $.plot("#placeholder", getSeriesObj());
```

To reset your data:

```
plot.setData(getSeriesObj());
plot.draw();
```

[Here's a jsFiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/FSw9H/).